# Reports for Cucumber-jvm: Any existing way to highlight only failed records from the table and mark others green

Tags: java, report, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I am wondering if there is any already existing way to highlight the failing records of the validation data table without marking the entire table as red?

For instance, let's say, we have the following step:

```
    Then we validate the following fields:
    | record1   | value1    |
    | record2   | value2    |
    | record3   | value3    |
    | record4   | value4    |
```

And let's say that out of these 4 records, 2 passed and 2 failed.
Currently, the entire table gets marked as red along with the step. What I want is to mark the step and the failing records as red but the passing records should be marked as green.

I don't if that's even possible to do or not or whether any such thing already exists or not, so I wanted to check out before I invested my time into building something like that.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By using scenario outline you will be able to test each record (By this way it only fails for record4) for example:

```
Scenario Outline :

Then I should see following record <Record> with value <Value>

Examples:
    |<Record>   | <Value>   |
    | record1   | value1    |
    | record2   | value2    |
    | record3   | value3    |
    | record4   | value4    |
```